# Given a complete set of time and space-like geodesics plus knowledge of how these geodesics vary is this enough to determine the metric?

Tags: metric-tensor, geodesics

I've been reading up on geodesics and metric tensors. I'm really curious about space and time-like geodesics. Just trying to get a better understanding of how the metric relates to these quantities. What would be the first step in calculating the metric based on the complete set of time and space like geodesics plus knowledge of how they change with respect to one another? Can you define a space-like geodesic in terms of a time like geodesic?